# How can i make HttpListener to listen on 443 on mac OS?

Tags: c#, macos, https, .net-core, httplistener

I am setting up a simple server based on HttpListener in .net core that needs to run on MacOS. Works great on http, but i need it to run on https (port 443. Tried a custom port but still no success)

On windows, it works with "netsh add iplisten" and binding the cert with "netsh add sslcert". And it works great for both http and https.

On Mac OS however, first thing i found out was to set up an alias for localhost "ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.9 up" so i'm allowed to start the httplistener.

That worked, and whenever i make a HTTP request to 127.0.0.9 i get the response i hard-coded in the browser.

Https still doesn't work. So i tried binding the certificate.
I used openssl to create a certificate => got a .p12 cert self-signed.
Used "httpcfg -add -port 443 -p12 server.p12 -pwd mypassword"
That worked, as i could see 2 files appeared in "~/.config/.mono/httplistener/" called 443.cer and 443.pvk.

However, if i navigate to https://127.0.0.9 i get an error connection reset in the browser.

I have no idea what else to try, and i can't find any answer.
Did anybody tried to do this on Mac OS?

```
        var ipAddress = "127.0.0.9";
        var httpListener = new HttpListener();

        var httpPrefix = string.Format("http://{0}/", ipAddress);
        var httpsPrefix = string.Format("https://{0}/", ipAddress);

        httpListener.Prefixes.Add(httpPrefix);
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add(httpsPrefix);

        httpListener.Start();
        WaitForNewRequest(httpListener);
```

In the "WaitForNewRequest(httpListener)" method i just write a hard-coded "hello world" response and wait for the next request. Nothing complicated.

Thank you!

Comment: Update: if i try to make the request with "curl -k https://127.0.0.9" i get this: 
:curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.9:443"

Comment: dug some more, found out about this "openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.9:443 -msg". It gives errno 54, and it says "write:errno=54
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
..............
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)"

Answer (score 0):

Ports below `1024` are privileged, you need to run your app as `root` to open them.

If you need to use `443` in production, I highly recommend using `apache` or `nginx` to listen on the `SSL` port and proxy the traffic to your `.net` code.