# HttpListener Permission Denied

Tags: c#, .net, macos, maui

I've encountered an issue using the `HttpListener`. I'm currently writing an desktop app with .net 8.0 and MAUI. I want to listen to `https://localhost:5000/callback`. If I try to listen it fails with `Permission denied`. I'm running this code on MacOS.

This is my code snippet:

```
using HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add(RedirectUri);
listener.Start();
```

It fails at the `Start` call. The weird thing is, if I run my NUnit tests it works flawlessly. If i call the same function from my MAUI App it fails.

Do MacOS desktop apps need something else for the permission? And if so why would the test then succeed.

Many thanks for any help or suggestion!

Comment: Does it help [How can i make HttpListener to listen on 443 on mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423331/how-can-i-make-httplistener-to-listen-on-443-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `Platforms/MacCatalyst/Entitlements.plist` and add this:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
<true/>
```

Then, exit out of VS for Mac, delete your `bin` and `obj` folders with `rm -rf bin obj` and restart VS for Mac.

This is required because app-sandbox is enabled by default, which puts a lot of restrictions on what your app can do.

If it still doesn't work, change this:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
```

to this:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<false/>
```